# There are 2 comboboxes as shown.I return 12 values in it.But i want to delete the value i selected in the first combobox from the second

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

### I want to delete the value I selected in the second one from the first.I'll do this with 12 comboxes. How can I do it cleanest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMalo.png)

```
        int[] Can = new int[12];    /*Array*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)  
        {
            
            Can[i] = i + 1;

          
        }

       
        z++;
        if (z <=1)
        {

            foreach (var value in Can) //Can DATA 
            {
                   
                    CanID1.Items.Add(value);  /*12 piece Can
                    CanID2.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID3.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID4.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID5.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID6.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID7.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID8.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID9.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID10.Items.Add(value);
                    CanID11.Items.Add(value);    
            }


        }
```

Comment: What did you try? The cb1.SelectedIndexChanged even should help. Here you can grab the item text and while cb2.Items contains text remove it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your question a bit more clear, but I think I get the gist of it.

I feel the best object to use would be `List<int>` for can instead of `int[]` to allow easy manipulation. I'm unsure if you want to be able to use the values again, but we can remove them for subsequent `ComboBox`'s.

```
 List<int> can = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
```

I have each `ComboBox` rebuild it's `Items` when the `DropDown()` occurs off of can.

```
private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (int item in can)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Upon `SelectedIndexChanged()` we just remove the selected value.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        can.Remove((int)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: Thank u so much.but I can still select the same IDs in two comboboxes